# Get 3 or more level categories in magento2

Tags: magento2

i'm getting the sub category for the below code,but still i want more categories which mean it  has sub categories of more levels how can i get this.

```
 foreach($categories as $category) {

            $cat = $this->getCategoryModel()->load($category->getId());
            $array[$category->getLevel()][$cat->getId()]= array('id' => $cat->getId(), 'level' => $cat->getLevel(), 'name' => $cat->getName(), 'url' => $cat->getUrl(), 'display_mode' => $cat->getDisplayMode(), 'image' => $cat->getImageUrl('wizard_icon'), 'description' => $cat->getWizardQuestion(), 'categories' => [] ); //In this line we get an a link for the product and product count of that category
            if($category->hasChildren()) {  //if category has children or not. If yes then it proceed in inside loop.
                 $children = $category->getChildrenCategories(); // $children get a list of all subcategories
                $array[$category->getLevel()][$cat->getId()]['categories']=  $this->get_categories($children); //recursive call the get_categories function again.
                }

        }
    return  $array;
```

Comment: Please update your question and provide your code which is missing

Answer (score 0):

Using Dependency Injection (DI)

> Sample File Path:
>   app/code/YourCompanyName/YourModuleName/Block/YourCustomBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace YourCompanyName\YourModuleName\Block;
class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    protected $_categoryHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false) {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        // select only active categories
        if ($isActive) {
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        }

        // select categories of certain level
        if ($level) {
            $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
        }

        // sort categories by some value
        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }

        // set pagination
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize); 
        } 

        return $collection;
    }

    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true) {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true);
    }
}
```

Now, we can use the functions in our view (.phtml) file as follows.

**get the list of all categories**

```
$categories = $block->getCategoryCollection(); 
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
}
```

**Using Object Manager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

// get the list of all categories
$categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryCollection->create();
$categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getUrl() . '<br />';
}
```

**Get all subcategories of parent category**

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $catId = 2;  //Parent Category ID
    $subCategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
    $subCats = $subCategory->getChildrenCategories();
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<ul class="sub-cat-ul">
    <?php
    foreach ($subCats as $subcat) {
        $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
        $subcaturl = $subcat->getUrl();
        $_imgHtml = '';

        if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
            $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
            $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        } ?>
        <li class="cat-li">
            <div class="cat-image">
                <a href="<?php echo $subcaturl ?>"><?php echo $_imgHtml;?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <h4><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?></h4>
                <a class="link" href="<?php echo $subcaturl ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('View more') ?></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: it give me parent sub and child category?

Comment: @testing i have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for response acually the above code which i have mention in my Qeustion was audit by magento team and they said method get_categories that reload the category by ID after loading the category collection.

Comment: This issue causes multiple queries instead of one and negatively affects site performance.

Comment: can you help to modify this code